# webkitfullscreenchange event not firing, when the element contains Flash

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, dom-events

I have an element that contains a video player: that video player can either be Flash or HTML5 based. I want to be able to make that element fullscreen (I know, only works in webkit at the moment) and run some resizing scripts when it happens.

Here is how I do it:

```
this.getEl('.fullscreen').bind('click', $.proxy(function() {
    this.getEl('#tpPlayer')[0].webkitRequestFullScreen();
}, this));
```

And the event listener:

```
this.getEl('#tpPlayer').bind('webkitfullscreenchange', function() {
    console.log('fullscreen change');
    $(this).toggleClass('tpPlayer tpPlayerFullScreen');
});
```

When `#tpPlayer` contains a `<video>` element, everything works fine: the element goes fullscreen, the event fires, the message is logged and the classes are toggled. However, when `#tpPlayer` contains a Flash `<object>`, the element goes fullscreen fine, but no event is fired (so the callback does not run either).

Why is this happening and how to avoid this?

Comment: I am afraid that if you don't have access to the Flash code you won't be able to communicate such actions between flash and Javascript.

Comment: Well, I don't actually want to communicate anything to Flash. I run a native method on an element that happens to contain a Flash object. And that method works, it just does not fire an event it supposed to fire.